# Expressjs App on Vercel, not installing peer dependencies

Tags: node.js, express, vercel, gltf

I'm building a small expressjs app that I host on vercel. Testing the app locally works fine, but when deploying and running on vercel, the require stack fails on my serverless function.

This is what vercel tells me :

```
2023-02-03T14:41:20.325Z    undefined   ERROR   Cannot find module 'ndarray-pixels'
Require stack:
- /var/task/node_modules/@gltf-transform/functions/dist/functions.js
- /var/task/_index.js
```

My package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "test - app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "_index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --experimental-fetch _index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@gltf-transform/core": "^2.5.1",
    "@gltf-transform/extensions": "^2.5.1",
    "@gltf-transform/functions": "^2.5.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "gl-matrix": "^3.4.3",
    "ktx-parse": "^0.4.5",
    "ndarray-pixels": "^1.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.9",
    "three": "^0.148.0"
  }
}
```

.

I've tried adding the build override on vercel, with no luck.

> npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Any help or pointers are much appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure if it's relevant to the question or not, but just thought I'd mention that `ndarray-pixels` is a regular production dependency and not a peer dependency. Does the error go away if `@gltf-transform/functions` is removed from the dependencies and app? That may help to narrow things down...

Comment: it sure is relevant, I debugged a bit with removing the different dependencies. And yes the error goes away, when removing @gltf-transform/functions. I managed to get my setup to work on heroku, so it might be a bug at vercel when installing and deploying

Answer (score 0):

This problem can happen if you accidentally send the `node_modules` folder to the git remote repository. If it is the case, remove the `node_modules` folder, create a `.gitignore` file if it not exists and just write `node_modules` inside the `gitignore` file.

Now you can:

```bash
git rm -r --cached .
git add --all .
git commit -a -m "Versioning untracked files"
git push
```

Comment: .gitignore is in place, with node_modules, and i've checked my repository for any "leftover" modules :) so sadly, this isn't the case.